# Replacing one font-awesome icon with another does not show the result

Tags: jquery, font-awesome

I am building a button and decorating it with some text, a bootstrap badge and a font-awesome icon.  Later I might want to change the font-awesome icon.  However, when I change the icon two things happen.  The original icon in the badge is removed and the new icon is installed -- but does not display.  The second thing I noticed is that the `:before` marker on the original icon is also removed but is not replaced when the new ocin goes in.

I have a [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/31501/)

```
const roomNameDiv = $("<div/>").addClass("nameDiv")
    .appendTo("#thing");
const button = $("<button/>").addClass("roomId")
    .addClass("itemName")
  .addClass("btn")
  .addClass("btn-sm")
  .addClass("btn-secondary")
  .addClass("p-0")
  .attr("data-info",
        "groupName" + ":" + "roomType" + ":" + "roomId")
  .append("roomId")
  .appendTo(roomNameDiv);
const buttonBadge = $("<span/>").addClass("buttonBadge")
  .addClass("badge")
  .addClass("badge-info")
  .addClass("mr-1")
  .prependTo(button);
var buttonBadgeIcon = $("<span/>").addClass("fa")
  .addClass("fa-user-plus")
  .addClass("fa-fw")
  .appendTo(buttonBadge);

window.confirm("continue: ");

buttonBadgeIcon.removeClass("fa-user-plus")
  .addClass("fa-user-minus");
```

I have also tried doing the following with the same results:

```
...
window.confirm("continue: ");

buttonBadgeIcon.remove();
buttonBadgeIcon = $("<span/>").addClass("fa")
  .addClass("fa-user-minus")
  .addClass("fa-fw")
  .appendTo(buttonBadge);
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Font-awesome version 4.7.0. I could not find an icon with class `fa-user-minus` in this version. That is the issue here. As a suggestion, try upgrading to Font-awesome version 5. It has the icons that you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you. Will have to choose a different icon.  I am stuck on 4.7 for now :/